# Why doesn't the for-loop make my wishes coming true?

Tags: javascript, loops, global-variables, var

Ok, Simply... I want to make this (which works perfectly, but is obviously too much writings when i have #b up to #b20):

```
$("#b" + 1).click(function () {
    $('.c').hide();
    $(".a" + 1).show();
});
$("#b" + 2).click(function () {
    $('.c').hide();
    $(".a" + 1).show();
});
```

Simple, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i += 1) {
    $("#b" + i).click(function () {
        $('.c').hide();
        $(".a" + i).show();
        alert('Hey'+i);
    });
}
```

**$("#b" + i)** is button on htmlpage, and     **$(".a" + i)** is the text which is supposed to be viewed on the page by clicking on the button. 
//So the text is with *class="c a1"*, *class="c a2"*, ...; and the button is with *id="#b1"*, *id="#b2"*...
But when I execute the code (Click on #b1, #b2, or...), .c hides (as expected), and the next step is only executed for i=50 (proved with the alert).

Any ideas?

Comment: b starts at 0, do you want that?  in your first line you say you just have #b with no number. please clarify.

Comment: A maybe cleaner approach would be to just give all buttons the same class (i.e. "btn") and then a `data-num` attribute with the actual number. Then you can just say `$(".btn").click(function() { var i = $(this).data("num"); /* rest of code */ });`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i += 1) {
    (function (j) {
        $("#b" + j).click(function () {
            $('.c').hide();
            $(".a" + j).show();
            alert('Hey'+j);
        });
    }(i))
}
```

Actually, this is a classic, you should read more about closures and about the fact that JS is a 'pass as value' language. But simply put:

The anonymous `function` sent as argument to the `click` function has a reference to the environment it was created in, and as so, has a reference to the `i` variable, which is precisely the same for every `function` created (one function is created at each iteration). So every anonymous function will have `i` with the last value of the loop.

By using another closure, you use the fact that JS passes argument as value, and not as reference: the `j` (even if you call it `i`, as I previously had) is not a reference to the `i`, but rather the value of `i` at the time it is passed to the function.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry that there's a duplication with another question. 
And thank you //for I fought with this question for 3 days//.